# Drawing Fonts on screen in C

Tags: c, fonts

I emulated a screen with the SDL library. I want to draw fonts on this screen, simply using a "draw_pixel" function I already made.

I searched a lot on the Internet. 
I found this website http://jared.geek.nz/2014/jan/custom-fonts-for-microcontrollers and the code works well. However it does not support variable-width characters

I only want to use source code.

Could you please tell me if there is a source code or a light library to draw fonts from pixels ?

EDIT : Here is my code I changed from M Oehm answer.

```
int DrawChar(char c, uint8_t x, uint8_t y, int r, int g, int b, SDL_Surface *rectangle, SDL_Surface *ecran, SDL_Rect position)
{
uint8_t i,j;

// Convert the character to an index
c = c & 0x7F;
if (c < ' ') {
    c = 0;
} else {
    c -= ' ';
}

const uint8_t* chr = font[c];
int w = chr[0];

chr++;

for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < CHAR_HEIGHT; i++) {

        if (chr[j] & (1 << i)) {
            draw_pixel(x+j, y+i, r, g, b, rectangle, ecran, position);
        }
    }
}

return w + CHAR_GAP;
}

void DrawString(const char* str, uint8_t x, uint8_t y, int r, int g, int b, SDL_Surface *rectangle, SDL_Surface *ecran, SDL_Rect position)
{
while (*str) {
    x += DrawChar(*str++, x, y, r, g, b, rectangle, ecran, position);
}
}
```

---

```
const unsigned char font[96][6] = {
{3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},          //
{3, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x00},          // !
{4, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03},    // "
```

Here is the result : The characters are still at the same size.
http://hpics.li/d54f000

**EDIT :** 
**The solution is here http://www.riuson.com/lcd-image-converter
You will have to change a bit the code because they are some mistakes, but it works.**

Answer (score 2):

You can easily extend the given code to variable-width characters. Change the definition of the font:

```
const unsigned char font[96][10] = {
    {3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},          //  
    {3, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x00},          // !
    {4, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03},    // "
    ...
};
```

The first entry is the width of the character. The second dimension must be chosen to accomodate the widest character. It can be 9 pixels wide in this example.

Then extend the `DrawChar` function to use the given width and alo to return the width that the drwing position should advance, which is the width of the character plus a certain gap. (You can make the gap a parameter, so that you can print double-spaced text.)

The `DrawString` function then makes use of the returned width:

```
int DrawChar(char c, uint8 x, uint8 y, uint8 brightness)
{
    uint8 i, j;

    // Convert the character to an index
    c = c & 0x7F;
    if (c < ' ') {
        c = 0;
    } else {
        c -= ' ';
    }

    const uint8* chr = font[c];
    int w = chr[0];

    chr++;

    for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < CHAR_HEIGHT; i++) {

            if (chr[j] & (1 << i)) {
                DrawPixel(x + j, y + i, brightness);
            }
        }
    }

    return w + CHAR_GAP;
}

void DrawString(const char* str, uint8 x, uint8 y, uint8 brightness)
{
    while (*str) {
        x += DrawChar(*str++, x, y, brightness);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Here's a more complete example which defines only some letters:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8;

char screen[25][80];

#define CHAR_HEIGHT 8
#define CHAR_GAP 2

const unsigned char font[96][10] = {
    [' ' - 32] = {1, 0x00},
    ['A' - 32] = {5, 0x3e, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x3e},
    ['B' - 32] = {5, 0x3f, 0x25, 0x25, 0x25, 0x19},
    ['D' - 32] = {5, 0x3f, 0x21, 0x21, 0x21, 0x1e},
    ['E' - 32] = {5, 0x3f, 0x25, 0x25, 0x25, 0x21},
    ['H' - 32] = {5, 0x3f, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x3f},
    ['I' - 32] = {1, 0x3f},
    ['L' - 32] = {4, 0x3f, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20},
    ['M' - 32] = {7, 0x3f, 0x02, 0x04, 0x18, 0x04, 0x02, 0x3f},
    ['O' - 32] = {5, 0x1e, 0x21, 0x21, 0x21, 0x1e},
    ['P' - 32] = {5, 0x3f, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06},
    ['R' - 32] = {5, 0x3f, 0x09, 0x19, 0x19, 0x26},
    ['S' - 32] = {5, 0x22, 0x25, 0x25, 0x25, 0x19},
    ['W' - 32] = {7, 0x07, 0x38, 0x0c, 0x03, 0x0c, 0x38, 0x07},
};

void DrawPixel(int x, int y, uint8 c)
{
    screen[y][x] = c;
}

int DrawChar(char c, uint8 x, uint8 y, uint8 brightness)
{
    uint8 i, j;

    // Convert the character to an index
    c = c & 0x7F;
    if (c < ' ') {
        c = 0;
    } else {
        c -= ' ';
    }

    const uint8* chr = font[c];
    int w = chr[0];

    chr++;

    for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < CHAR_HEIGHT; i++) {

            if (chr[j] & (1 << i)) {
                DrawPixel(x + j, y + i, brightness);
            }
        }
    }

    return w + CHAR_GAP;
}

void DrawString(const char* str, uint8 x, uint8 y, uint8 brightness)
{
    while (*str) {
        x += DrawChar(*str++, x, y, brightness);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    memset(screen, '.', sizeof(screen));

    DrawString("HELLO WORLD", 2, 2, 'O');
    DrawString("MISSISSIPPI", 8, 10, '#');

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) printf("%.80s\n", screen[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @M Oehm thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but it doesn't work. Indeed if I change the first entry (the character width) then it draws more pixels next to the character But it doesn't change the with of it

Comment: Hmmm, I have tested this code, albeit not with a full alphabet. Have you copied my code or just made changes?

Comment: Then please replace the two subroutines completely. It's likely that you missed something.

Comment: Please look at my edit. I copied your code, but as a result it doesn't work.

Comment: Please, be serious. You print two (!) characters that even have the same width and then conclude that the code doesn't work. The code works. Period. I've added a complete working example. It prints a fake bitmap to a char buffer.

Comment: I tried your complete example. I get the error _unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported_ at the end of the font table (`};`).

Comment: Yes. I didn't want to define a whole font, so I just replaced some characters. The "designated inilialisers" are the `['A' - 32]` syntax inside the array initialisation. But, please, show a bit of effort yourself. You probably already have a fond. Extend that to make at least the I narrow and the M and W wide ans test it. Me, _I'm_ not interested in printing variable-width fonts. _You_ are. Where I come from, we have a saying: You have to do the eating yourself if you want to get fat.

Comment: I understand your assumption. I thought your "complete" example did work. Are you telling me I have to rewrite for each letter, each byte ? If this is the case your proverb makes senses. Where I come from, we have another  saying: There is no need to reinvent the wheel. I know somebody has already the answer and is willing to share it.

Comment: There's no need to reinvent the wheel, indeed. But SO isn't about ready-made solutions. (That might explain the downvotes on your question.) I had seen the solution you linked and that it is easily extended to proportional fonts. Of course you must provide the extra data, the character width, for this code.The linked article explains how to create the character data, so I assumed you had already done that. But the existing data is easily extended: Just prepend the old char width (6) to all chars and then adjust the narrow (I, J, L )and wide ones.(M, W).

Comment: Ok I'll spend time on it later . But as I'm working with a team on a global project. I have to progress on a more important work.